# UWP change NavigationViewItem height

Tags: uwp, windows-10-universal, uwp-xaml, navigationview, fluent-design

[image: Comparison image]

On the image above, you can see my app (left) and Groove Player (right). I want to make NavigationViewItem height big like Groove Player, but I don't know how. I tried playing with Padding and MinHeight but it doesn't look the same.

I want to do the same for the AutoSuggestBox and the Settings button, that are part of NavigationView.

```
    <NavigationView x:Name="navView" IsSettingsVisible="True">
        <NavigationView.AutoSuggestBox>
            <AutoSuggestBox QueryIcon="Find" PlaceholderText="Search"></AutoSuggestBox>
        </NavigationView.AutoSuggestBox>

        <NavigationView.MenuItems>
            <NavigationViewItem x:Name="button1" Icon="Favorite" Content="Button 1" Tapped="Button1_Tapped"/>
            <NavigationViewItem x:Name="button2" Icon="Save" Content="Button 2" Tapped="Button2_Tapped"/>
        </NavigationView.MenuItems>
    </NavigationView>
```

Answer (score 0):

> UWP change NavigationViewItem height

For your requirement, you could edit `NavigationViewItem` template. Right click `NavigationViewItem` in the xaml designer -> Edit Template -> Edit a copy.

[image]

If you want to  change `NavigationViewItem` height, you could modify `LayoutRoot` height. And then modify `SelectionIndicator` height correspondingly.

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Height="50" Control.IsTemplateFocusTarget="True">
 ......
<Rectangle x:Name="SelectionIndicator" Fill="{ThemeResource NavigationViewSelectionIndicatorForeground}" Height="40" Opacity="0.0" Width="6"/>
```