# UWP Remove highlight from NavigationView

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I want to remove the highlights from the NavigationView Menu Items

[image: Example image]

How can I make it so that on some MenuItems the highlight thing doesn't move to the item?

Comment: It's in the template . Edit the template

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just simple override the default Color Resource by adding the following code in App.xaml or in the Page where the NavigationView control placed.

in App.xaml

```
 <Application.Resources>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="NavigationViewSelectionIndicatorForeground" Color="Transparent" />
</Application.Resources>
```

**OR** in page where NavigationView control exist

```
 <Page.Resources>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="NavigationViewSelectionIndicatorForeground" Color="Transparent" />
</Page.Resources>
```

Answer (score 0):

For your requirement, you could [modify](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47786811/7254781) `NavigationViewItem` style, and set the width of  `SelectionIndicator` Rectangle as 0. You could also use the following style directly.

```
<Style TargetType="NavigationViewItem">
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource NavigationViewItemForeground}"/>
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{ThemeResource NavigationViewItemBackground}"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{ThemeResource NavigationViewItemBorderBrush}"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="{StaticResource NavigationViewItemBorderThickness}"/>
    <Setter Property="UseSystemFocusVisuals" Value="True"/>
    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="NavigationViewItem">
                <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Height="40" Control.IsTemplateFocusTarget="True">
                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="PointerStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                            <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">
                                <VisualState.Setters>
                                    <Setter Target="LayoutRoot.(RevealBrush.State)" Value="PointerOver"/>
                                    <Setter Target="LayoutRoot.Background" Value="{ThemeResource NavigationViewItemBackgroundPointerOver}"/>
                                    <Setter Target="RevealBorder.BorderBrush" Value="{ThemeResource NavigationViewItemBorderBrushPointerOver}"/>
                                    <Setter Target="ContentPresenter.Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource NavigationViewItemForegroundPointerOver}"/>
                                </VisualState.Setters>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                <VisualState.Setters>
                                    <Setter Target="LayoutRoot.(RevealBrush.State)" Value="Pressed"/>
                                    <Setter Target="LayoutRoot.Background" Value="{ThemeResource NavigationViewItemBackgroundPressed}"/>
                                    <Setter Target="RevealBorder.BorderBrush" Value="{ThemeResource NavigationViewItemBorderBrushPressed}"/>
                                    <Setter Target="ContentPresenter.Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource NavigationViewItemForegroundPressed}"/>
                                </VisualState.Setters>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Selected">
                                <VisualState.Setters>
                                    <Setter Target="LayoutRoot.Background" Value="{ThemeResource NavigationViewItemBackgroundSelected}"/>
                                    <Setter Target="RevealBorder.BorderBrush" Value="{ThemeResource NavigationViewItemBorderBrushSelected}"/>
                                    <Setter Target="ContentPresenter.Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource NavigationViewItemForegroundSelected}"/>
                                </VisualState.Setters>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="PointerOverSelected">
                                <VisualState.Setters>
                                    <Setter Target="LayoutRoot.(RevealBrush.State)" Value="PointerOver"/>
                                    <Setter Target="LayoutRoot.Background" Value="{ThemeResource NavigationViewItemBackgroundSelectedPointerOver}"/>
                                    <Setter Target="RevealBorder.BorderBrush" Value="{ThemeResource NavigationViewItemBorderBrushSelectedPointerOver}"/>
                                    <Setter Target="ContentPresenter.Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource NavigationViewItemForegroundSelectedPointerOver}"/>
                                </VisualState.Setters>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="PressedSelected">
                                <VisualState.Setters>
                                    <Setter Target="LayoutRoot.(RevealBrush.State)" Value="Pressed"/>
                                    <Setter Target="LayoutRoot.Background" Value="{ThemeResource NavigationViewItemBackgroundSelectedPressed}"/>
                                    <Setter Target="RevealBorder.BorderBrush" Value="{ThemeResource NavigationViewItemBorderBrushSelectedPressed}"/>
                                    <Setter Target="ContentPresenter.Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource NavigationViewItemForegroundSelectedPressed}"/>
                                </VisualState.Setters>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="DisabledStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Enabled"/>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                <VisualState.Setters>
                                    <Setter Target="RevealBorder.BorderBrush" Value="{ThemeResource NavigationViewItemBorderBrushCheckedDisabled}"/>
                                    <Setter Target="LayoutRoot.Opacity" Value="{ThemeResource ListViewItemDisabledThemeOpacity}"/>
                                </VisualState.Setters>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="IconStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="IconVisible"/>
                            <VisualState x:Name="IconCollapsed">
                                <VisualState.Setters>
                                    <Setter Target="IconBox.Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
                                    <Setter Target="IconColumn.Width" Value="16"/>
                                </VisualState.Setters>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                        <Rectangle x:Name="SelectionIndicator" Fill="{ThemeResource NavigationViewSelectionIndicatorForeground}" Height="24" Opacity="0.0" Width="0"/>
                    </Grid>
                    <Border x:Name="RevealBorder" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"/>
                    <Grid x:Name="ContentGrid" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="40">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition x:Name="IconColumn" Width="48"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ToolTipService.ToolTip>
                            <ToolTip x:Name="ToolTip"/>
                        </ToolTipService.ToolTip>
                        <Viewbox x:Name="IconBox" Child="{TemplateBinding Icon}" Margin="16,12"/>
                        <ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentPresenter" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" ContentTransitions="{TemplateBinding ContentTransitions}" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                    </Grid>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```